# Solr performance: 6.6.0 vs 7.2.1

Tags: performance, solr, lucene, load-testing, solrcloud

I'm running loadtests on two SolrCloud clusters. Clusters are identical except that one has Solr 6.6.0 with fixed schema, and the other has Solr 7.2.1 with managed schema. Java and garbage collector setting are same on both. Hardware is same too.

Search corpus is identical too: ~400k documents, each size ~5KB size
I'm loadtesting with two boxes running jmeter v.3.3.
Solr 6 starts struggling at 200 threads on each jmeter box. Solr 7 almost dies at 100 threads - so apparently Solr6 is a lot more performant with this setup.

Could just Solr version alone cause such a big difference in performance? If not - where should I look to determine what gives this difference?

Comment: Start by running a profiler and see where the JVM spends it time.

Comment: Are you reproducing your Solr 6 scehma.xml exactly with the managed Solr 7 schema? If so, can we see the Solr 6 schema.xml as well as a representative query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup that was fixed schema vs managed schema difference. If you update your index frequently then managed schema will slow searches down dramatically.